# Adding validator to a number of fields

Tags: 7, forms

I have a number of fields added to multiple content types. Using the [Field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module takes much time, so I decided to validate them programmatically. Which hook should I use to validate fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `hook_form_alter()`, check the form ID matches one of those that you're interested in, then add a validation handler to the form. The validation handler will perform your validation against the form fields. Something like

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_ids = array(
    'article_node_form',
    'page_node_form'
  );

  if (in_array($form_id, $form_ids)) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_field_validate_callback';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_field_validate_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['values']['field_x'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    form_set_error('', 'Field X cannot be empty.');
  }
}
```

I don't know of another way to do this as [`hook_field_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) is only called for the module that implements the field type.

Comment: Thanks. my site is multilingual. LANGUAGE_NONE currently works but should I always use it?

Comment: I think you'd get away with checking the language of the node, something like `$langcode = $form['#node']->language`...but I'm not totally sure